# Adding Text/watermark to ‘Download Plot’ button image in Plotly

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

Is there any way to add a text/watermark to the image which is downloaded by clicking on the “Download Plot” button ("toImageButtonOptions") in Plotly figures?
Reference code:

```
config = {
‘toImageButtonOptions’: {
‘format’: ‘png’,
‘filename’: ‘download_image’,
        }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using [templates](https://plotly.com/python/templates/):

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

draft_template = go.layout.Template()
draft_template.layout.annotations = [
    dict(
        name="draft watermark",
        text="DRAFT",
        textangle=-30,
        opacity=0.1,
        font=dict(color="black", size=100),
        xref="paper",
        yref="paper",
        x=0.5,
        y=0.5,
        showarrow=False,
    )
]

fig=go.Figure()
fig.update_layout(template=draft_template)
fig.show()
```

**Output:**
[image]